# storage class, storage duration, file scope, lifetime, linkage confusion

Tags: c++, static, scope

When talked about a `C++/C` variable, the **standard ISO document** mentions `storage class`, `storage duration`, `file scope`, `lifetime`, and `linkage`.

I want to understand the basic clues and how they are related to each other. But after reading the `ISO` documents, I cannot find a clear logic map for these concepts.

Could you help clarify it? I hope I can use there concepts to analyze my programming problem.

The `ISO documents` sections:

- C99 6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers
- C99 6.11.2 Linkages of identifiers
- C++2003 7.1.1 Storage class specifiers
- C++2003 7.5 Linkage specifications
- etc.

Comment: search this should be already on Stackoverflow I am quit sure.

Comment: @JBL I re-edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Storage class** specifiers are a part of the `decl-specifier-seq` of a declaration syntax. They control two independent properties of the names introduced by the declaration: their **storage duration** and their **linkage**. **Storage class** specifiers:
>
> - `auto` - automatic storage duration (until C++11)
> - `register` - automatic storage duration. Also hints to the compiler to place the variable in the processor's register (deprecated)
> - `static` - static or thread storage duration and internal linkage
> - `extern` - static or thread storage duration and external linkage
> - `thread_local` - thread storage duration (since C++11)
>
> **Storage durations**:
>
> - `automatic` storage duration. The variable is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated on end. All non-global variables have this storage duration, except those declared `static`, `extern` or `thread_local`.
> - `static` storage duration. The variable is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends. Only one instance of the variable exists. All global variables have this storage duration, plus those declared with `static` or `extern`.
> - `thread` storage duration. The variable is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the variable. Only variables declared `thread_local` have this storage duration. `thread_local` can appear together with `static` or `extern` to adjust linkage.
>     (since C++11)
> - `dynamic` storage duration. The variable is allocated and deallocated per request by using dynamic memory allocation functions.
>
> **Linkage**. A name that denotes object, reference, function, type, template, namespace, or value, may have linkage. If a name has linkage, it refers to the same entity as the same name introduced by a declaration in another scope. If a variable, function, or another entity with the same name is declared in several scopes, but does not have sufficient linkage, then several instances of the entity are generated.
>
> The following linkages are recognized:
>
> - *No linkage.* The name can be referred to only from the scope it is in.
> - *Internal linkage.* The name can be referred to from all scopes in the current translation unit.
> - *External linkage.* The variable can be referred to from the scopes in the other translation units.

[Reference.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: `Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.` (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I've edited your answer to mark the quotes as quotes.

Comment: I have a doubt: Do every variable with internal linkage has static storage duration?

Answer (score 0):

While I had an intuitive understanding of the notions, I was quite curious about what they truly meant; what the rules were and why they were what they were.

So I wrote a [full blog post](http://norswap.com/c_scope_duration_linkage/) about it, which is as thorough as it's going to get without being the standard, but is much simpler to understand.

Here are the key insights:

(An object in C is a variable or a function)

> The **scope** of a declaration is the part of the code where the
>   declaration is seen and can be used.
>
> Note that this says nothing about whether the object associated to the
>   declaration can be accessed from some other part of the code via
>   another declaration!
>
> We identify a unique object by its memory: the storage for a variable
>   or the function code.
>
> **Duration** indicates whether the object associated to the declaration
>   persists throughout the program's execution (*static duration*) or whether it is allocated
>   dynamically when the declaration's scope is entered (*dynamic duration*).
>
> **Linkage** is what determines if multiple declarations of the same object
>   refer to the same object, or to separate ones.

About **Linkage**, if we simplify a bit:

- no linkage: the declaration refers to a unique object
- internal linkage: all declarations in a compilation unit refer to the same object
- external linkage: all declarations with external linkage in the program refer to the same object

Finally, a handy rule:

> One can determine the linkage and duration of any declaration using
>   only three rules (most prioritary rule first):
>
> - Within functions, declarations without `extern` have no linkage.
> - Within functions, declarations without `extern` or `static` have automatic   duration. Any other declaration, at any scope, has static
>     duration.
> - Within a compilation unit, objects have internal linkage if there is a   declaration with the `static` storage class specifier. This
>     declaration must   happen before any `extern` declaration, and there
>     cannot be any declaration   without storage class specifier (or a
>     compilation error ensues). Otherwise,   they have external linkage.

I hope this helps!