# C++ Delete temporary node in a member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, set

I am implementing a class Set, and there is member function, ironically called member, which returns true, if the value being passed is in the set, and false otherwise. My question is that, if I am creating a temporary node to iterate over to search for this value, do I need to delete this temporary node when I am done with it to return the memory to the heap, as it is not being returned from the function?

In this class, the node is embedded as a private struct in the class Set like this:

```
private:
  //Precondition: linked list is sorted in ascending order
  struct Node {
     int value;
     Node* link;
  };
  Node* list;
  static Node* cons(int x, Node *p);
```

and the function I'm referring to is:

```
bool Set::member(int x) const {
   if(list == nullptr) 
      return false;

   Node* tempNode = list;

   while(tempNode != nullptr) {
      if(tempNode->value > x) 
         return false;
      if(tempNode->value == x) 
         return true;
      tempNode = tempNode->link;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `tempNode` is not being allocated, you are pointing it to the same place `list` is pointing.

Comment: Ah right okay, I guess this follows the principle of using delete whenever using keyword new, which I did not. Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming your Set is for an assignment. After the assignment, if you want to know more about pointers and what exist, I suggest you to take a look into [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one). A lot of times (IMHO, most of the time) you dont have to use `new/delete` explicitly.

Comment: Duly noted, I will do that. Thanks!!

Comment: @wendelbsilva, well, there are plenty of cases when you have to use `new` explicitly even in the brave new world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

`tempNode` is just a non-static local variable with [**automatic** storage duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784519/storage-class-storage-duration-file-scope-lifetime-linkage-confusion); it's scope is confined to the begin and the end of the function. It is **automatically deallocated** when the function returns.

Comment: Non-static local variables have a well-defined name - they are called _automatic_ variables.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, yes - wanted to add that, I was just looking for a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your `member` function does not allocate any heap memory (no `new` or `malloc` calls). The `tempNode` variable (of size `sizeof(Node*)`) is going to be allocated on the stack.

When the function exits, the activation record for the whole function (containing `tempNode`) gets automatically deallocated, so no need to do further cleaning.

The code is correct as it is.

Comment: Wrong. Who says anything about the variable being allocated on stack? Most likely, it won't. And what is 'activation record'?