# Why does this kind of initialization not work?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a struct called Node. Node accepts a double and stores it into a variable named `value`.

I'm trying to make a new struct. My first example works, but the second doesn't. The second example doesn't give a compiler error and it builds just fine, but when I try to access a value from the node later on, it gives me `-9.25596e+061`.

This code works fine:

```
Node *firstNode; 
Node *newNode = new Node(value); 
firstNode = newNode;
```

This code doesn't:

```
Node *firstNode; 
Node newNode(value); 
firstNode = &newNode;
```

I could just use the first three lines of code, but I want to know why the other code doesn't work. Is it fundamentally wrong or is the syntax just slightly off?

Comment: Maybe it's all in a function and `newNode` goes out of scope in the 2nd example?

Comment: We need more code. Where are you using the value? In another function?

Comment: @cad - Correct, this code is in a different function than the code that is accessing the variable. Is that a problem though? Why does the first one work then?

Comment: @Pikamander2 The first one is allocated on the heap and will stay around until you `delete` it. The second one is allocated as a local variable on the stack and will go out of scope as soon as the function returns. At that point you have an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Pikamander2 you need to understand the difference between allocating memory and using an addres of a variable. If you see that you can use both, it means, you do not have this understanding, and you really need to learn the basics.

Comment: @Pikamander2 read this http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables are [**automatic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784519/storage-class-storage-duration-file-scope-lifetime-linkage-confusion) - they go out of scope when the function returns and any further access to them (like via pointers as you did) is **undefined behavior**.

`new` allocates memory on the **free store**, which is independent of scopes or lifetimes. It can only be freed by `delete` or by the OS when the program exits.

Comment: A side note - you should _always_ `delete` memory which you allocated using `new` when you no longer need it. Otherwise you'll be leaking memory.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Thanks for the info!